# Entity with ID type String error

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, derby

I'm having the following entity when i do the persist Im getting dump,
I moving to the field string value(this is how the model defined there is ID type string with value such as (vacation,WORK_ACCIDENT...so i cant change it) and the error is

Invalid character string format for type INTEGER.

```
@Entity
public class LeaveReType {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private String id;
```

I having another entity with ID type string and when i move to it number the persistence
working OK ,can i use some annotation for ID to ignore this restriction ?

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLDataException: Invalid character string format for type INTEGER.
Error Code: 20000
Call: INSERT INTO LESTTYPE (ID, AVAILABLEBALANCE, ENTITLEMENT, NAME, PENDINGITEMS) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [5 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(LESTTYPE [id=WORK_ACCIDENT, name=Work Accident, entitlement=n/a, availableBalance=n/a, pendingItems=0 pending items])
```

I also tried with and i getting the same error

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@TypeConverter(dataType = Long.class, name = "id")
private String id;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930762/generate-an-auto-generated-value-of-a-field-under-java-hibernate-id-generated

Comment: @baraky- I have tried to add the annotation @Column(columnDefinition="ID1", name = "id") and the error was the same...

Comment: Did you try http://stackoverflow.com/a/8090756/1651233

Comment: @baraky- yes with the column as i write in the provisos comment but not sure what else i should put there...

Comment: @JeanTennie - it doesn't seem that this particular id should be auto-generated. Why not just take off the `@GeneratedValue` annotation entirely, and populate the column yourself?

Comment: @Perception- i have remove the  annotation  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE) and the same error still exist

Comment: @JeanTennie - add your error stack trace to the question.

Comment: The error is from the database.  How did you create the tables and what is the type for the Id column in the table?  And as suggested above, you cannot use sequencing for a string type.  If you are using DDL generation, try ensuring you drop the tables first as it may have been created with a number type.

Comment: @Chris I have just created the entities manually and didnt create tables... how should i change my annotation to support it,do you have an idea?

Comment: What does the LESTTYPE table look like in the database then?  An EclipseLink DDL generation example is shown here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/DDL

Answer (score 0):

If you database type is NUMBER are you want your object type to be String you should use a Converter to convert the type.

i.e.
@TypeConverter(dataType=Long.class)

But really, if you database type is NUMBER you should use a numeric type in Java.  You could still have get/set method that take String if you wish.  Also using @GeneratedValue on a String type is odd.

Comment: Thanks James but I was tried to add  such annotation like in your example and im getting the same error,I have edited my post at the end with the annotation that i was added ...

Comment: You also need @Convert("id") (converters are named objects like sequences)